# Create delegate at runtime

Tags: c#

I have a method:

```
int SomeMethod(object[] args)
{
    // ...
}
```

And I want to create a delegate with the same return type, but with a variable number of arguments (`Func<int,int>` or `(Func<float,int,int>`, etc...) which calls this `SomeMethod`.

```
Delegate CreateDelegate(Type delegateType)
{
    var delegateMethodInfo = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");

    // ???
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: The problem here is *not* creating the delegate, but creating the method body behind it. The method behind the delegate needs to invoke `SomeMethod` with all of its arguments passed in an array.

Comment: Create the delegate in a conditional block, you cannot make changes to the logic at the runtime.

Comment: I've just thought of one way of doing this, generating IL code, but I have never done this and have no knowledge of how to do this.

Comment: None of those delegate types can work, the method only takes a single argument.  You *must* use a `Func<object[], int>` delegate.  Which trivially solves your problem.

Comment: To rephrase my question, how do I generate the body of a delegate with a unknown number of arguments. The problem here isn't creating the delegate necessarily but to create the body of it.

Comment: @HansPassant The point of the code I'm writing is to assign fields of delegate type at runtime. These fields just can't always be of type `Func<object[], int>`

Comment: I solved it by generating IL code with ILGenerator.